# Jquery $.ajax to website, return value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post to my own domain through a Greasemonkey script on another webpage. The script pull some info from the webpage, uses ajax to post to my domain and my domain sends back a value.

I always get readyState = 0?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://botsunauthorized.net/bots4captcha.php", 
    data: { 
        url: str
    },
    success: function(data,success) {
        alert(data+'-'+success);
    },
    error: function(data,success) {
        $.each(data, function(key,valueObj){
            alert(key + "/" + valueObj );
        });
    }
});
```

When I use the `$.each` function, it says `readyState = 0` and I get no value from my domain. I've done some research and it may be because the scripts are not on the same server? Is there an easy way to get around this or am I not going to be able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that URL your site, and are you sure it's just not a case of the same-origin policy.

Comment: This is a limitation of `Cross Origin Resource Sharing`. To circumvent this, perform the logic on your server by doing `file_get_contents()` or using `cURL` to return the data to you. This wil bypass it.

Comment: Yes that url is my own domain. The Greasemonkey script is on another website.

Comment: need to CORS enable your script then, or return jsonp via GET

Comment: I did that charlietfl! Works! Thank you.